# Install Apache2 using msiexec /qn. Does not set ServerAdmin

Tags: windows, apache

I am currently trying to install Apache2 on a Windows Server with CygWin. I use a precompiled .msi from: [here](http://apache.imsam.info//httpd/binaries/win32/httpd-2.2.22-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8t.msi).

To install it, I use the following Command: `Msiexec /i httpd-2.2.22-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8t.msi INSTALLDIR="C:\\Apache2" SERVERADMIN="mail@example.com" SERVERNAME="example.com" SERVERDOMAIN="example.com"  /qn`

However the given `SERVERADMIN`doesn't get set in the Configuration File. Even though the [Documentation say so](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html). If I am calling the `httpd.exe` it responds: 
`Syntax error on line 163 of C:/Apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
ServerAdmin takes one argument, The email address of the server administrator`

The Config looks like this:

```
#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin 
#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName :80
```

Obviously the `ServerAdmin` and also the `ServerName`, are not set by the installer.

Do you have any ideas what to do? As a fallback maybe we could set it directly in the Config. Do you have any `Command Line`to do so (I can't use the GUI, but I can use `CygWin`commands)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after writing this Question, the Answer immediately popped up in front of me. If you uninstall Apache with `msiexec /x`, it won't remove the old ConfigFiles. If you reinstall it on the same directory, it will just take the old Configs, no matter, what you pass the installer.